# Which model fields can be used with a radio widget(via a modelform)?

Tags: django, django-forms

When I read the documentation about modelforms and widgets it looks like you can use any widget on any modelform but that there are certain default widgets used for form fields corresponding to modelform fields. I'm able to render a radio input using a form field but not with a modelform field.

I have tried many different things, but I just **can't seem to render a RadioSelect widget of a modelform field which comes from a model field. Is this even possible**?

Btw, my goal is to let the initial value of the radio input correspond with the current value of the model field(A boolean).

**Attempt 1:**

```
# views.py
class SettingsView(FormView):
    template_name = 'settings.html'
    success_url = 'settings/saved/'
    form_class = NicknameForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = request.user.get_profile()
        if request.POST['show_nickname'] == 'False':
            profile.show_nickname = False
            profile.save()         
        elif request.POST['show_nickname'] == 'True':
            profile.show_nickname = True
            profile.save()

        return super(NicknameFormView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        To be able to use 'show_nickname_form' instead of plain 'form' in the template.
        """        
        context = super(NicknameFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["show_nickname_form"] = context.get('form')
        return context


# models.py 
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                unique=True,
                                verbose_name='user',
                                related_name='profile')
    show_nickname = models.BooleanField(default=True)


# forms.py
from django import forms
from models import Profile    

CHOICES = (('shows_nickname', 'Yes'), ('hides_nickname', 'No'))

class NicknameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('show_nickname',)
        widgets = {
            'show_nickname': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'choices': CHOICES}),
        }
```

Part from my template:

```
        <form action='' method="post">
            {{ show_nickname_form.as_ul }} {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Save setttings">
        </form>
```

The form that is rendered from `{{ show_nickname_form.as_ul }}`:

```
<li><label for="id_show_nickname_0">show nickname:</label> 
<ul></ul>
</li> 
<div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='1BqD6HJbP5e01NVwLtmFBqhhu3Y1fiOw' /></div>`
```

**Attempt 2:**
    # forms.py
    from django import forms
    from models import Profile

```
class NicknameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('show_nickname',)
        widgets = {
            'show_nickname': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

**Attempt 3**

```
# forms.py
CHOICES = ((True, 'On',),
  (False, 'Off',))

class NicknameForm(ModelForm):
    show_nickname = ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES, initial=True , label='')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('show_nickname',)
```

This renders the radio input fine but I need it to take the initial value of the corresponding model field `show_nickname` instead of the constant `True`.

I am using `Django 1.4` btw.

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: And what happens when you try either of these?

Comment: The radio input is badly rendered, I edited the original post to show what is rendered after attempt 1.

Comment: Btw, when I leave out the `widgets = {'show_nickname': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'choices': CHOICES}),}` line the form is rendered as a checkbox.

Comment: Do you have any idea what could be wrong? Could you confirm you are able to implement a radio from a BooleanField of a model? At this point it seems that the conclusion most likely to be true is that you simply can't implement a RadioSelect widget on a BooleanField. But the docs are not really clear which widgets can be used with which Fields imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it into a `ChoiceField` instead of a `BooleanField` with a choice for each and a `RadioWidget` in order for it to display radio buttons.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField

If you want to keep the boolean field, you will most likely have to do some hacking to create your own field/widget.

---

```
# views.py
class SettingsView(FormView):
    template_name = 'settings.html'
    success_url = 'settings/saved/'
    form_class = NicknameForm

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        """
        Returns an instance of the form to be used in this view.
        """
        form = super(SettingsView, self).get_form(form_class)

        if 'show_nickname' in form.fields:
            profile = self.request.user.get_profile()
            form.fields['show_nickname'].initial = profile.show_nickname

        return form

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = request.user.get_profile()
        if request.POST['show_nickname'] == 'False':
            profile.show_nickname = False
            profile.save()
        elif request.POST['show_nickname'] == 'True':
            profile.show_nickname = True
            profile.save()

        return super(NicknameFormView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        To be able to use 'show_nickname_form' instead of plain 'form' in the template.
        """
        context = super(NicknameFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["show_nickname_form"] = context.get('form')
        return context
```

Comment: I know how I can implement a RadioWidget (look at attempt 3) but the problem I have been having all along is letting the initial value of the radio correspond to the boolean value of `show_nickname` in my model. I thought Implementing it like in attempt 1 would 'automatically' take the initial value of the model. Do you know how to let the value of the radio correspond to the value of `show_nickname`(boolean) of the Profile model for a logged in user?

Comment: Where are you using the form? You can usually hook methods to modify form data before the forms are rendered.

Comment: @Bentley4 If you add the view, I can try and help with that.

Comment: @Bentley4 Check my edit and let me know if it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Wait, are you amazing? Yes you are, thank you so much!!! For these things class based views are really crufty imo. : s

Comment: No problem. I agree, they are useful for very simple pages, but once you start adding in your own tweaks, they get out of hand fast...